# swapping lines between Session.save() . what changes happens in the output . Kindly see the comment in the code. i'm new in java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What happens in the output  if I swap lines is not understandable to me 
        Following changes in the output happen.if i don't swap

```
    //Hibernate: insert into Person (age, name) values (?, ?)
    //Hibernate: insert into Address (city, house, person_personId) values 
    //(?, ?, ?)

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new 
        Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        // one to one---test
        //What if we swap line 28 and 29


        session.save(person);
        session.save(address);


        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();



        and here is the output when i swap:
        //Hibernate: insert into Address (city, house, person_personId) 
       //values (?, ?, ?)
      //Hibernate: insert into Person (age, name) values (?, ?)
     //Hibernate: update Address set city=?, house=?, person_personId=? 
    //where addressId=?
```

Comment: What is the relationship between Address and Person entities ?

Comment: OneToOne unidirectional relationship

Answer (score 0):

If you fill in the dependencies in the entities currently, there will be no difference.

`session.save` does not go to the database at this point (may call a sequence if the id is a sequence generated for example but that's it). It only registers a given entity within the Persistence Context.

Actual `INSERT` happens upon `commit`.